# Stop the scheduled Periodic Job?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-7.0-nougat, android-jobscheduler, android-job

I have been using the `android-job` Evernote library. I have job which is running continuously every 30 minutes. I have been using code to schedule the job

```
new JobRequest.Builder(TrackJob.TAG)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(30), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
```

Now I want to stop this Job when a user clicks on a button. How I will achieve this?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/evernote/android-job/issues/84

Comment: Please have an eye on those answers

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

`JobManager.instance().cancelAllForTag(your-job-tag);`

or

`JobManager.instance().cancel(your-job-id)`

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the Job ID:**

```
int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .setExecutionWindow(30_000L, 40_000L)
            .setBackoffCriteria(5_000L, JobRequest.BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setExtras(extras)
            .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
```

**Canceling By Button:**

```
Button _button = new Button(this) ;

_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      JobManager.instance().cancel(jobId);
    }
});
```

**Note:**

You can use `SharedPreference` to store the `jobId` for later use. I mean if you want to cancel the job after application re-starts.

According to the Wiki, the job can also be canceled with the `Job.TAG`.I tried it but wasn't able to cancel it. (V1.2.5)